# Locked question, want to answer

Tags: feature-request

[This question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/46351/apartment-lease-renewal-is-this-rate-increase-normal) is locked.  I wanted to post an answer saying that the past rent really doesn't matter.  The poster has three options:  accept the increase, find a new apartment, or negotiate the rent (with find a new apartment the backup).  This is not in the range of answers on the question so far, and I think it is a useful view.  I don't know what the torrent of answers has been to cause the lock-it has been 21 hours and I know people are sensitive to rent increases.  How do we allow on-topic answers (if you think mine is) and stop the (presumed) stream of bad ones?

Answer (score 2):

The linked question had a series of comments that resulted in a total of 8 moderator flags. I deleted the comments and to stop new ones, put a temporary lock (1 day) which I've just removed, if you wish to offer an answer.